# Rails: issue authenticating with youtube via youtube_it gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube

I'm getting the error:

> YouTubeIt::AuthenticationError: BadAuthentication

I just want to confirm my authentication details:

```
@client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:username => "my_youtube_acount@gmail.com", :password =>  "password_to_gmail", :dev_key => "youtube_api_credentials_key")
```

So,

1. :username is my full gmail address? or just the name before @gmail.com? Or something else?
2. :password is the password to above gmail account?
3. :dev_key is a youtube_data server API key that I've generated from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

Does that all look right? Why would I be getting an authentication error? I've verified the credentials manually several times.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to go into my google profile settings to allow less secure apps to have access (I guess apps that don't use Oauth?)

[image]